# For inside a function

Tags: javascript

I can't understand this function:

```
function power(base, exponent) {
  var result = 1;
  for (var count = 0; count < exponent; count++)
    result *= base;
  return result;
}

show(power(2, 10));
```

How can `show(power(2, 10))` be equal to `1024`, if the base and exponent don't have any relation inside the function?

Thanks

Comment: i cleary see loop with `0 .. exponent` and multiply operation `*= base`

Answer (score 1):

The key part that gives the relation between base and exponent inside the function is this :

`count < exponent;`

This means that the loop, in which `result` is multiplied by `base`,
runs exactly `exponent` times.
Which is precisely the definition of exponentiation:
From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation) :

> exponentiation corresponds to repeated multiplication;

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, now I understand that

Comment: @swayziak Please do me the honor of accepting my answer, to recognize my contribution to your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution

Comment: Just click the tick underneath the vote count on my answer to mark your question answered there

Answer (score 0):

this function does the job. for 0 to 10, multiply the value by 2 which is the meaning of pow(2, 10).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend stepping through it with a debugger.  `base` and `exponent` are related in the function: `base` is essentially multiplied by itself `exponent` times, because `exponent` is the counter on the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It does have a relationship.

Base = 2
Exponent = 10

What it will do is FOR(COUNT < Exponent), so it will loop through the function for 10 times. And multiply the result each time by base. which is 2.

So

1. 1 * 2 = 2 (New result = 2)
2. 2 * 2 = 4 (New result = 4)
3. 4 * 2 = 8 (New result = 8)
4. 8 * 2 = 16
5. 16 * 2 = 32
6. 32 * 2 = 64
7. 64 * 2 = 128
8. 128 * 2 = 256
9. 256 * 2 = 512
10. 512 * 2 = 1024

Answer (score 0):

2 to the power 10 is 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2
You initiate a variable to 1, which is the identity element of multiplication (1 x N = N), and then to calculate A to the power B,

```
result = 1
FOR 1 TO B
    result = result * A
return result;
```